# issue in fetching data in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

Everyone, I am having one table named as **orders** which contains one of its field named *date_created*. Now I want to fetch data from the particular range of date. I am attaching code:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
orders o,
accounts_store a WHERE  o.date_created >= '2018-06-27' AND o.date_created <= '2018-06-28'
    AND a.account_id = '1'
    AND a.store_id = '1'
```

But this fetches data of the only date 2018-06-27. I am not getting data of 2018-06-28 so what should I do to fetch data of both date?
can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your `WHERE` clause is off.  Use the following to target the 27th *and* 28th of June:

```
WHERE o.date_created >= '2018-06-27' AND o.date_created < '2018-06-29'
```

The problem with `o.date_created <= '2018-06-28'` is that it means any date on or earlier than *midnight* on 28 June, i.e. it basically excludes the 28th completely.  Instead, I used `o.date_created < '2018-06-29'`, which includes the entire day of 28 June.

Answer (score 1):

To get expected result change the where statement in the query on `WHERE  o.date_created >= '2018-06-27' AND o.date_created < '2018-06-29'`

This problem may arise when the field *date_created* has type DateTime because an implicit conversation happens. It means that values interpret by DB like `WHERE o.date_created >= '2018-06-27 00:00:00:000' AND o.date_created <= '2018-06-28 00:00:00:000'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
orders o,
accounts_store a WHERE  o.date_created >= '2018-06-27' AND DATE_FORMAT(o.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2018-06-28'
    AND a.account_id = '1'
    AND a.store_id = '1'
```

If you have index on date_created then the above query wont use that index. In this better use the below condition
o.date_created >= '2018-06-27' AND o.date_created < '2018-06-29'